# Is there a way to update Priorities without PUT erasing all your data?

Tags: firebase, angularfire

Two questions: first, is it true that the only way to update '.priority' via REST is by using PUT, which forces you to rewrite all the other values?  And I'm afraid to ask, but does that also apply to the Javascript SDK?

Second, is there maybe some other way other than using Priorities to order your collection 'server-side'?

Sorting things on the client doesn't work for me because I'm using a masonry-type plugin for layout which goes bonkers whenever the order changes client-side, but it seems to work fine server side.  I'm using PHP to degrade the '.priority' value over time, lowering the item's position in the collection, but I'm forced to rewrite every other field at cron run.  It works, but it would be better to just be able to update '.priority' or some other value that controls the position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Question 1: .priority via REST API**

You can set the priority without modify the record by calling PUT on the .priority directly. These examples are [found in the REST API doc](https://www.firebase.com/docs/rest-api.html):

[image]

So, to reiterate, add `.priority` into the URL.

**Question 2: Hacking masonry sorting in Angular using the data store?**

If you haven't explored your options here, there are several libs dedicated to integrating masonry and angular which you may want to check out (e.g. [angular-masonry](https://github.com/passy/angular-masonry)). You may also have luck address sorting data in masonry directly, in its own SO question, rather than trying to solve it with your data store, which seems like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

The records in Firebase are sorted lexicographically, so you have three options:

1. name your items so they sort in the desired order
2. use push ids, which are ordered chronologically
3. use priorities to enforce a sort order other than the record id's natural sorting

Keep in mind that [numeric keys, when mixed with lexicographic strings, cause behave strangely--err, by design--in Chrome. And, tangentially related, such a debate has waged that the ECMAScript standard will actually be changed to force them to correct it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3186770/chrome-re-ordering-object-keys-if-numerics-is-that-normal-expected)

Comment: Thanks!  If you want to see how I implemented the masonry layout