# where query in firebase

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, firebase

I am new in Firebase. I have problem while executing query:

```
new Firebase("https://blazing-fire-2739.firebaseio.com/users")
        .startAt($scope.user.email) //karank@ocodewire.com
        .endAt($scope.user.email)
        .once('value', function(snap) {
           console.log('accounts matching email address', snap.val())
        });
```

This shows me null.

In Firebase:

```
users
   -JxFNEu31LJ0Efy8PnX5
      email: karank@ocodewire.com
      firstname:karan 
      lastname: sofat
```

Please Help

Comment: Try putting orderBychild('email') in front of that. Also, equalTo() FTW.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.startAt` and `endAt` doesn't accept a string, it accept a number where to start/end at. So you would have to change to

```
new Firebase("https://blazing-fire-2739.firebaseio.com/users")
  .startAt(1)
  .endAt(50)
  .once('value', function(snap) {
    console.log('accounts matching email address', snap.val());
});
```

Or just leave out the `endAt()` altogether.

Comment: It is important to note that this will not work unless the user objects are set with a priority. This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24102307/1526037) shows the ordering rules. You will need [`.setPriority()`](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/firebase/setpriority.html) or [`.setWithPriority()`](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/firebase/setwithpriority.html)

Comment: You can see that this does not work in [this plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/oTIqlEwzovH8da2soVqN?p=preview)

Answer (score 2):

In the documentations for [`Query.startAt()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/) and [`Query.endAt()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/), under 'Arguments', you will see that the first argument, `value`, is:

> The value to start [or end] at. The argument type depends on which `orderBy*()` function was used in this query. Specify a value that matches the `orderBy*()` type. When used in combination with `orderByKey()`, the value must be a string.

The [Querying Data section of the Web Guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/#section-queries) says,

> With Firebase database queries, we can selectively retrieve data based on various factors. To construct a query in your database, you start by specifying how you want your data to be ordered using one of the ordering functions: `orderByChild()`, `orderByKey()`, `orderByValue()`, or `orderByPriority()`. You can then combine these with five other methods to conduct complex queries: `limitToFirst()`, `limitToLast()`, `startAt()`, `endAt()`, and `equalTo()`.

- If the user objects have a priority, and an orderBy is not specified for the `Query`, the query will sort by priorities and startAt/endAt by indices will work. You can use [`.setPriority()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/) or [`.setWithPriority()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/).
- If the user objects do not have a priority set, and the `Query` has no `orderBy*()`, `snapshot.val()` will be null.

For your query, if the user objects do not have priorities set, sorting by the `email` child will make `startAt`/`endAt` work, like so:

```
new Firebase("https://blazing-fire-2739.firebaseio.com/users")
    .orderByChild('email')
    .startAt($scope.user.email)
    .endAt($scope.user.email)
    .once('value', function(snap) {
       console.log('accounts matching email address', snap.val())
    });
```

Here is a working [plnkr example](https://plnkr.co/edit/5nyJSxTK5vleNFFv41AJ?p=preview) of this query.

---

**However, as Kato pointed out in the comments,**

> "As a general recommendation, `orderByChild()` supersedes priorities and should be preferred. Priorities will eventually be phased out in favor of child fields."

Since your goal is to locate a single specific user by her email address and since there should be only one user with a given `email` child value, you can,

- Order the `Query` object for `/users` by the `"email"` child key;
- Query for the user object for which the `email` child is `equalTo(<email>)`.

For example:

```
var usersRef = new Firebase("https://blazing-fire-2739.firebaseio.com/users");
userRef.orderByChild("email").equalTo($scope.user.email).once("value", function(snapshot) {
  if(snapshot.exists()){
    console.log(snapshot.val());
  }
});
```

And here is a working [plnkr example](https://plnkr.co/edit/xzxaD2Cudu8fHS6K0jv0?p=preview) of this second query.

For more information, check out the documentation for [`Query.equalTo()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/) and [`Query.orderByChild()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/).

Important side-note: when ordering by a child key, if you know what the indices for your query will be, "you can define them via the `.indexOn` rule in your Security and Firebase Rules for better performance." Check out the [Indexing Data documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/) for more info.

---

It might be helpful to read over the [Retrieving Data Guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/).

To inspect your Firebase data in the browser and see objects' priorities, you can use [Vulcan](https://web.archive.org/web/20160314231150/https://www.firebase.com/blog/2014-09-30-vulcan.html) -- an awesome Google Chrome extension. This is what Vulcan looks like in the Chrome DevTools:

[image: vulcan]
<sub>(source: [firebase.com](https://www.firebase.com/resources/images/blog/vulcan-editor-crud.png))</sub>

---

*Hope this helps!*

Comment: Great work! Covers most of the details. As a general recommendation, `orderByChild()` supersedes priorities and should be preferred. Priorities will eventually be phased out in favor of child fields.

Comment: Thanks @Kato, that is great to know.

Comment: Kind of curious how with equalTo, snap.key() doesn't actually return the key of the object returned... see plunkr:
http://plnkr.co/edit/BbWn3DpNjbXtx8pgH8j8?p=preview

Comment: Looks like you can't use "value", but instead "child_added". I suppose that makes a little sense.