# Auto ordered keys inside JavaScript Object

Tags: javascript

I create an object, and then pass on all his keys. It turns out they are ordered! How to avoid it? Is it real?

```
var obj = { "A": 1, "C": 2, "B": 3 };
for (var key in obj)
{
  //receiving in turn A, B and C instead of A, C, B
}
```

Comment: visit->http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3186770/chrome-re-ordering-object-keys-if-numerics-is-that-normal-expected

Comment: The order of keys in not specified within an object (as per the javascript specification), don't ever rely on it. You will find different behaviours in different browsers, maybe even between different versions of the same browser.

Comment: I am very disappointed =( Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Here is  Jsfiddle and it displays- A,C,B-
https://jsfiddle.net/abvzLc5d/

Comment: I think that was going on in the selected browser. For example, if you specify the keys "1", "3", "2", the result will be, as I described above [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/abvzLc5d/1/)

Comment: If the Keys are integers, then please refer to the link @SagarNaliyapara provided.
If the Key's are having letter in the beginning, then it displays the way you  expect.