# JavaScript Object.keys(hashmap) returns order

Tags: javascript, object, hashmap

Hi I am working on JavaScript `Object.keys()`. According to Mozilla, `Object.keys()` return an array whose elements are strings and the ordering of the properties is `the same as` that given by looping over the properties of the object manually. However,  I did use `Map`, instead

```
let hashmap = {
        1000: 'M',
        900: 'CM',
        500: 'D',
        400: 'CD',
        100: 'C',
        90 : 'XC',
        50 : 'L',
        40 : 'XL',
        10 : 'X',
        9  : 'IX',
        5  : 'V',
        4  : 'IV',
        1  : 'I'  
    }

for (let key of Object.keys(hashmap)){
    console.log(key);
}


console.log(Object.keys(hashmap));
```

return value is
`Array ["1", "4", "5", "9", "10", "40", "50", "90", "100", "400", "500", "900", "1000"]` I supposed to get the Array in the reversed order. Can any one tell me the reason why it looks like this ? Also, when looping over the object, it did not follow the order as well. Thanks! What is the root cause.

Comment: I believe the answer is found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3186770/chrome-re-ordering-object-keys-if-numerics-is-that-normal-expected

Comment: Yes, they were kind of discussing about this question, but they did not say clearly the reason. Just like this is ECMAScript specification ! .... !

Comment: Not relevant to the question but just FYI: a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) is different from an object literal (like `{ key: 'val', key2, 'etc' }`).

Answer (score 0):

The result of "console.log(Object.keys(hashmap))" is exactly as expected - it should be in the order the data is stored, not the order in which it was added. See the example given by Mozilla under ["array-like object with random key ordering"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys).

When you manually loop over the object, you will get the same order (as it is stored). Another way to loop is:

```
for (let key in hashmap){
  console.log(key);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I know the output will be like that, however, I have no idea why it is like that?